# Google Analytics cross domain configuration through Myleadpages subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking, universal-analytics, issue-tracking

I have the issue with the cross-domain tracking though I studied all the cases and official Google guidelines.

I have the website **www.familyhealthchiropractic.com**

I also have the lead form page **`https://my.leadpages.net/leadbox/143c56873f72a2%3A10c91346ab46dc/5674368789118976/`**  where the facebook paid traffic lands to

After you fill the form above (https://my.leadpages.net/) you are redirected to thank you page **https://drdaniel.leadpages.co/newpatient-ty-adjustment-for-45/**  where I track goal (destination url /newpatient-ty-adjustment-for-45/)

I want to save the original source of traffic (for example facebook) when I finally arrive at **`https://drdaniel.leadpages.co/newpatient-ty-adjustment-for-45/`** thank you page from **`https://my.leadpages.net/leadbox/143c56873f72a2%3A10c91346ab46dc/5674368789118976/`**  page

Now, the traffic source is converted to refferal (or direct when I exlude refferals)
Could you please take a look? Many thanks

Comment: You said you've studied all the cases, what have you tried? I would try to pass the user's client ID from one site to the other.

Comment: Hi, is there any difference? How do I do this?

Comment: Telling us what you've tried lets us know what to not suggest, and demonstrates your level of understanding. Passing Client IDs is a tricky business; I recommend using Google Tag Manager and following this guide http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/06/16/cross-domain-tracking-with-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Ok, I will try, but what is wrong with my configuration right now, everything is set correctly as far as I can see